# Can i check in-App purchase in the ios simulator?

Tags: ionic2, in-app-purchase, ios-simulator

can i check in-App purchase in the simulator ? because i don’t have iPhone real device so,i couldn’t able to create provisioning profile certificate so what is the way to check in-App purchase in the simulator

Answer (score 0):

with Xcode 9.1 now and previous, I can't really finalize transaction, but made that

`id <SKPaymentTransactionObserver> observer = self;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];`

in the appDelegate falls into `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`. That's still nice.

Using `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`(from TargetConditionals.h) here and there you can implement a very lot of code and check it, of course your UIs, including sending payment requests to Apple. At the last time you must have a Device. By the way it's an error to publish anything on the App Store without having success in tests on at least one Device.